# What does OR 0x80 do?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In Bitwise operation, what does | 0x80 do? I know (& 0xFF) is convert value to 8 bit integer but how about (| 0x80) ?
I have the following code:

```
const buf = createHash('sha256').update('test').digest()

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const ubyte = buf.readUInt8(i)
    const shifted = (ubyte >> 1) | mask
    destBuf.writeUInt8(shifted, i)


    mask = (ubyte & 1) * 0x80 // mask is 0 or 128
  }
```

Can anyone explain that for me?

Comment: `|` is the bitwise or operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR

Comment: do you understand why  `& 0xFF` convert value to 8 bit integer? same about `| 0x80`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x...` means that what comes next is an hexadecimal number.
`0x80` is the hexadecimal representation of the number 128. In binary, this equals `10000000`.

The `|` character is the bitwise or operator. Suppose you have a 8-bit number:

```
a = xxxxxxxx
```

with x being either a `0` or a `1`. Now, masking this number with `0x80` means:

```
xxxxxxxx | 10000000 = 1xxxxxxx
```

So it basically means you will have a 1 for your leftmost significant bit, while keeping all the other bits the same.

Now, in your code you use this mask in the line:

```
const shifted = (ubyte >> 1) | mask
```

What this does is takes the number `ubyte`:

```
ubyte = xxxxxxxy // x and y can be either 1 or 0
```

It shifts it right by onw digit:

```
ubyte >> 1 = zxxxxxxx // y gets lost, and z is a 0 if ubyte was unsigned.
```

Now it masks this number with your mask. When the mask is 128, the result is:

```
(ubyte >> 1) | 10000000 = 1xxxxxxx
```

So you will have a 1 as your most significant bit, and the other bits are unchanged.

Comment: Very good answer. Just make sure you write 10000000 and not 1000000 when you convert 0x80 to binary. The last instance looks right.

Answer (score 2):

It combines the bits of both participating numbers with the logical "or":

```js
const b= 0x7;

function tst(a,b){
  console.log(a.toString(2).padStart(8)+" first number: "+a)
  console.log(b.toString(2).padStart(8)+" second number: "+b)
  console.log((a | b).toString(2).padStart(8)+" bitwise overlay: "+(a|b))
  console.log("----")    
}

[0x80,0x6A,0x70,0x8f].forEach(a=>tst(a,b))
```